# Strange memory leak related to DataContext and PropertyChanged event

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have a windows service written in C#.

After running for a couple of days it will be using about 2GB of ram.

Using ".NET Memory Profiler" I noticed that there is a hugely increasing number of instances of a certain T_TurbineEventLog class. 
These objects come from a loop that fetches them every minute through a LINQ-to-SQL query (lots of them each time), and on certain occations I keep a reference to few of them.

The memory profiler told me that most of these objects are only kept alive through a shortest root path resembling the following (from my memory):

> root -> ... -> T_TurbineEventLog -> PropertyChanged -> ...(eventhandlers) -> IdentityManager -> ...Cache -> T_TurbineEventLog[] -> T_TurbineEventLog.

Thus, to me it seems that the few T_TurbineEventLog objects that I keep live myself for good reasons hold an indirect link to the totality of original SQL Query results through an event handler (keep in mind that the above shows the *shortest* root path).

I read the objects inside a small `using (var db=new MyDataContext...)`, so I guess the datacontext ought to unsubscribe from the PropertyChanging event, but for some reason hasn't.

I have google'd to the best of my abilities but this doesn't seem like a known problem. 
So what can I be doing wrong?

The solution so far has been to set `ObjectTrackingEnabled=false`, which actually removes the leak.

Comment: It looks like your solution to set `ObjectTrackingEnabled = false` is the best solution. Realize that the context keeps a hold of all objects that it fetches so that it can watch for changes. Just disposing it doesn't remove the event hooks on INotifyPropertyChanged/INotifyPropertyChanging thus they are retained longer than they should be. Since you don't need the change tracking, removing it should not only fix your memory leak, but improve performance as well.

Comment: I have also seen this scenrio exactly how you describe it. In my situation I had to go through a few places where a small "using" statement was used to work with the datacontext, and use the ObjectTracking=false option. I was using Ants profiler and saw the number of instances of a particular class within the datacontext continually climb.

Comment: Are you using the entities outside of the using(...) scope in which the DataContext is declared? Just because you kill off the data context, references to other things may exist. If you are using the entities outside the data context scope, you need to create non-LINQ / POCO classes that mirror the data model and deep copy into these. If you want examples, I can provide them.